# Planning to switch to Shared Hosting from Cloud Server

Tags: cloud, plesk, shared-hosting

we are using Vultr Cloud Server, with 3 vCPU and 8gig RAM, our actual website data size is less than 10gig, we have a visitors of almost 20k per month. On our server, we usually receive notification about swap memory usage threshold reach. We set it to 95%, on our vultr dashboard we have a monthly bandwidth
Usage:  104.51 GB (4%)
Inbound:    7.19 GB
Outbound:   104.51 GB.

My question is, can we migrate to a Shared Hosting? Im thinking A2Hosting Web Hosting their highest plan. We want to migrate to a shared hosting so we dont need to think about some technical aspect on the server.

I hope someone can enlighten us about this issue. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that your question isn't a programming question; but a "should we do <something>?" question which elicits opinions/discussions, which are offtopic here in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry about that, where can i post this question?

Comment: That's a good question.  Unfortunately, I have no idea as quite a bit of these techinical stack exchanges don't permit discussions/opinions-based questions.